# Xamarin.Forms iOS Facebook SDK Update Not verify

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use Xamarin.Forms, but I do the necessary actions on the iOS side, but Facebook does not verify the update.

and I'm new to this problem I had no such problems in advance.

I using plugin: Xamarin.Facebook.iOS (4.39.1)

[image]

SDK is up to date, although I have done all the necessary applications, my problem is not solved.

```
 using System;
 using System.Linq;
 using Firebase.Analytics;
 using Foundation;
 using Google.TagManager;
 using Plugin.FirebasePushNotification;
 using UIKit;
 namespace XXX.iOS
 {
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public bool disableAllOrientation = true;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        Facebook.CoreKit.Settings.AppID = "xxx";
        Facebook.CoreKit.Settings.DisplayName = "xxxxx";

        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(); 
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
        TagManager.Configure();

        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

        GoogleConversionTracking.Unified.ACTConversionReporter.ReportWithConversionId("xxxx", "xxxx", "0.00", false);
 Facebook.CoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);


    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
    {
        if (disableAllOrientation == true)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    }
    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
    }

    public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

    }
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {

        FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
    }

    public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Connect();
       // FacebookClientManager.OnActivated();
        Facebook.CoreKit.AppEvents.ActivateApp();

    }
    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        return Facebook.CoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl(app, url, options);

       // return FacebookClientManager.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        Analytics.HandleOpenUrl(url);
        return 
 Facebook.CoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.SharedInstance.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication,annotation);
        ///eturn FacebookClientManager.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);        
    }
    public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers and store the application state.
        // If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate when the user quits.
        var lastObject = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Subviews.Last();
        if (lastObject != null)
        {
            UIVisualEffect blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.FromStyle(UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark);
            UIVisualEffectView visualEffectView = new UIVisualEffectView(blurEffect)
            {
                Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds
            };
            lastObject.AddSubview(visualEffectView);
        }
        base.DidEnterBackground(application);
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Disconnect();
    }

    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        var lastObject = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Subviews.Last();
        if (lastObject != null)
        {
            var lastSub = lastObject.Subviews.Last();
            lastSub.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }
        base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);
    }
    public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        UIPasteboard.General.Items = new NSDictionary[0];
        base.WillTerminate(uiApplication);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh ! spontaneously improved. :)

Comment: What do you mean about not Verify? If you are using Xamarin to develop your projects generally we utilize Nuget to update the packages. Your verifying tool seems to check the native pod library, it is not Xamarin part.